# pytest selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

После нажатия на кнопку войти, сайт перебрасывает на новую страницу, однако driver работает все еще со стартовой, какие есть способы сменить страницу на новую, которая открылась после нажатия ?

Comment: А конкретный пример можно? Обычно помогает костыль в виде `waiter`а, который ждёт какого-нибудь события, типа появления элемента, который есть на новой странице, но нет на текущей и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос устарел, для работы с всплывающими окнами нужно использовать:
switch_to_window(window_handle)

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать `time.sleep(2)` (к примеру, две секунды), после этого тот же `driver.current_url` работает корректно